# Is a localized Mobile App considered bad and prone to removal from Apple/Google's perspective?

Tags: android, ios, appstore, apple

For the occasions that I've been offering SaaS, I've been asked to develop Apps that are pretty much a clone of regular e-commerce webpages, but with a few features like notifications and, well, being an App in itself. The thing is that it's localized to wherever my client operates, so if a guy asks me for an App to sell clothes in a 5 KM Radius, wouldn't it be viewed as unuseful and bad from Apple or Google in terms of their quality demands for apps? Since it would only be useful for people in that radius, and completely unuseful for the rest of the world.

So, do they disencourage this type of apps? If not, do they not care at all? Or do they dislike it?

I sense that, since apps only ever show at search results when people purposefully search for them, Apple nor Google should have a problem with these kind of apps, but that's just intuition.

Comment: Note that especially Apple does not like white-label apps where you merely re-skin and reconfigure the same app for a new client. But by themselves, highly local apps should not be a problem.

Comment: @amon that's quite another concern, why do they not like it? I mean, as long as both clients are happy, they might as well leave it be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google and Apple do not discourage these types of apps. They will help in that they will limit downloads by the countries that you select.

Users who download your app and find out they it will not work for them will probably uninstall or, worst, give your app a bad review and rating.

I would suggest making it explicitly known where you app works in the description. That should help limit the people who download your app and will not be able to use it in their area.

Comment: Thank you! I always had deep inside a concern about this, because I have developed quite a few and uploaded them to both stores. It would be a nightmare and a huge money loss if they were taken down, given the fact that some hardly rich 100 downloads at best